# Need Help to Fix my Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, backup, mysql

I'm a newbie on bash script, what i'm try to do is to make a bash script for running 2 kind of process of backup for mysql, first is to dump all mysql database into single dump file and another is to backup each database into single file, i search around to get some tips to make a bash script and the result as below, but seem is not working as my expectation, i try to execute the script but nothing happen, glad some one help me to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y")
BACKUP_DIR="/nas/mysql"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump

backup_all_dump(){ 
find /nas/mysql/all_dump -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/all_dump/$TIMESTAMP"
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --events --all-databases | gzip > "/$BACKUP_DIR/all_dump/$TIMESTAMP/dump.sql.gz"
}

backup_all_users(){ 
find /nas/mysql/all_users -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/all_users/$TIMESTAMP"
databases=`$MYSQL -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)"`
  for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --databases "$db" | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/all_users/$TIMESTAMP/$db.gz"
done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y")
BACKUP_DIR="/nas/mysql"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump

backup_all_dump(){ 
find /nas/mysql/all_dump -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/all_dump/$TIMESTAMP"
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --events --all-databases | gzip > "/$BACKUP_DIR/all_dump/$TIMESTAMP/dump.sql.gz"
}

backup_all_users(){ 
find /nas/mysql/all_users -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/all_users/$TIMESTAMP"
databases=`$MYSQL -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)"`
  for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --databases "$db" | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/all_users/$TIMESTAMP/$db.gz"
done
}
```

You need to call the function

```
backup_all_dump
```

You need to call the function

```
backup_all_users
```

Comment: Dear Sir, is it possible i just execute the script and running those process without calling function? Glad for help and TQ so much

Comment: Add these two lines at the bottom of your code to execute the functions when the code is executed: backup_all_dump [[ line break ]] backup_all_users